# How to call methode in pic 18F4550 with c language (compiler)

Tags: c, microcontroller

## update

I'm using pic 18F4550 with microchip v8.63 and C compiler.

I'm trying to make a color sensor. When a led burns a whant to go for example methode red.
In OOP is that simple to go to other methods, but how can you do that in C for microchip?

```
void main(void) 
{ 
    my code here....
    
    // Leds are connected here.
    if(PORTBbits.RB4 == 0) { //red
        LATDbits.LATD0 = 1;     
    }
    else if(PORTBbits.RB5 == 0) { //green
        LATDbits.LATD1 = 1;
    }
    else if(PORTBbits.RB6 == 0) { //blue
        LATDbits.LATD2 = 1;
    }
        // LDR is connected here.
    // 
    if(PORTAbits.RA0 == 1) {
        if(PORTBbits.RB4 == 0) {
            int red = PORTBbits.RB1;    // test.
            colorRed();     
        }
        else if(PORTBbits.RB5 == 0) {
            int green = PORTBbits.RB1;
            colorGreen();
        }
        else if(PORTBbits.RB6 == 0) {
            int blue = PORTBbits.RB1;
            colorBlue();
        }   
    }
}
void colorRed(void) 
{
    LATDbits.LATD0 = 0;
           // other code here

}

void colorGreen(void) 
{
    LATDbits.LATD1 = 0;
}

void colorGreen(void)
{
    LATDbits.LATD2 = 0;
}
```

These are the errors:

```
..\code\main.c:56:Warning [2058] call of function without prototype
..\code\main.c:60:Warning [2058] call of function without prototype
..\code\main.c:64:Warning [2058] call of function without prototype
..\code\main.c:69:Error [1109] type mismatch in redeclaration of 'colorRed'
..\code\main.c:74:Error [1109] type mismatch in redeclaration of 'colorGreen'
..\code\main.c:79:Error [1504] redefinition of 'colorGreen'
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Compiler warnings? Compiler errors? Program not doing what you expect?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? If this is your entire program, you probably need to put the contents of `main` inside an endless loop, and implement something to examine the chip's inputs periodically.

Comment: I just want to call a method. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add forward declarations ("prototypes") for the functions before the definition of `main`.

```
void colorRed(void);
void colorGreen(void);
void colorBlue(void);
```

Without these, the compiler assumes a function type of `int colorRed()`, where `int` mismatches with `void` and `()` mismatches with `(void)`.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, `main` should implement an endless loop which checks the chip's inputs and modifies the outputs.

Comment: what did you mean with endles loop in main? can you give an example?

Comment: @yannick: If `main` returns on an embedded processor, that is usually a form of crash. The chip cannot do anything until it is reset. A reset may occur immediately or after a predetermined time, but it will likely reinitialize global variables. Or it might never happen. Resetting is equivalent to a reboot, and it is not the right way to implement much of anything. So, do not allow `main` to return. Instead implement an endless loop.